# graphic entry in .mdx ebdict database file

Tags: database, mdx, graphic

I'm having problem building MDX file using [mdxbuilder](http://www.mdict.cn/download/MdxBuilder.zip) for ebdict dictionary reader. This entry cannot show a graphic as this: 
`<a href="sound://test.spx"><img src="playicon.jpg"></a>`
Can Anybody Help Me?I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is case sensitive, you need to use a closing img-tag as:

```
 <a href="sound://test.spx"><img src="playicon.jpg"></img></a>
```

I hope this is helpful.